# What should the bounds of integration be for calculating the marginal distribution function from a joint distribution function?

Tags: probability, density-function, marginal-distribution

[image]

I calculated $c=\dfrac{1}{8}$. To find $f_y(y)$, I integrated $f(x,y)$ from $-y$ to $y$. What should the bounds be to find $f_x(x)$?

I'm confused because x depends on y. Should the bounds just be $x$ to $\infty$?

Comment: To get $f_x(x)$ you need to $y$ integrate $(x,\infty)$ as you had guessed, since for $y\lt x$, the density function $=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A figure indicating the range of $(X, Y)$ often helps to determine the integral bounds and solve problems like this.

In this problem, the range of $(X, Y)$ is given by
$$-y \leq x \leq y, \ 0 < y < \infty,$$
which corresponds to the highlighted area (in light blue).

[image: Integral_bounds]

As such, the marginal density of $Y$ is given by
$$f_Y(y) = \int_{-y}^y f(x,y) dx = \int_{-y}^y c(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y} dx;$$
and the marginal density of $X$ is given by
$$f_X(x) = \begin{cases}\int_x^\infty f(x,y) dy = \int_x^\infty c(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y} dy & \text{for } x \geq 0;\\ \int_{-x}^\infty f(x,y) dy = \int_{-x}^\infty c(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y} dy & \text{for } x < 0.\end{cases}$$
Remark 1: The integral bounds to get $f_X(x)$ depend on the value of $x$ (being positive or negative), which can be illustrated straightforwardly from the figure.

Remark 2: One may notice that the resulting $f_X(x)$ could also be summarized into a "one-liner" formula, given by
$$f_X(x) = \int_{\left|x\right|}^\infty f(x,y) dy = \int_{\left|x\right|}^\infty c(y^2 - x^2)e^{-y} dy \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
These integral bounds are implied by the fact that
$$-y \leq x \leq y \Longleftrightarrow y \geq x \text{ and } y \geq -x \Longleftrightarrow y \geq \left|x\right|.$$
The resulting $f_X(x)$ would then be a function of $\left|x\right|$.

Comment: So could I integrate from |x| to $∞$ and have $f_x(x)$ not be piecewise?

Comment: @Alec Yes, you could integrate from $\left|x\right|$ to $\infty$, which is correct. Technically, the resulting $f_X(x)$ would then be a function of $\left|x\right|$, which is still a piecewise function. I have updated the solution to reflect this, thanks.